# First order by uppercase & lowercase

Tags: mysql

I have a few records which start with lowercase & uppercase.

```
SELECT * 
FROM wording 
ORDER BY word ASC;
```

Lanza
Mensi
Mhiob
blackbery
umbre
apple
Etios
Iomio

````
I am trying to order this by A-Z and a-z, something like
```none
Etios
Iomio
Lanza
Mensi
Mhiob
apple
blackberry
umbre
````

So, all the word which is starting with capital come first and after then all lowercase words.

Comment: you can use ASCII Method to get desired result. It will sort Value on the basis of Numeric ASCII Value of Character it means if we Sort data ascending it will sort Capital Letter First. ASCII of (A-Z: 65-90) and ASCII of (a-z: 97-122)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think ASCII function might help you -

```
SELECT * FROM wording
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ASCII(word) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, word DESC;
```

Comment: What if  i want reverse order like 
`Mhiob
Mensi
Lanza
Iomio
Etios
umbre
blackberry
apple`

Comment: Just use DESC in place of ASC.

Comment: no its give me 
`umbre blackberry apple Mhiob Mensi Lanza Iomio`

Comment: You can try the edited query.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too:

```
select * 
from wording 
order by binary(word) ASC;
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> word
> Etios
> Iomio
> Lanza
> Mensi
> Mhiob
> apple
> blackbery
> umbre
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=265f3ce5e1e81cc303531b8744f64853)

The binary sorting would put capital letters before lowercase ones

Answer (score 1):

you can use ASCII Method to get desired result. It will sort Value on the basis of Numeric ASCII Value of Character it means if we Sort data ascending it will sort Capital Letter First. ASCII of (A-Z: 65-90) and ASCII of (a-z: 97-122)

`SELECT * FROM wording ORDER BY ASCII(word) ASC;`

Output:

```
Etios
Iomio
Lanza
Mensi
Mhiob
apple
blackbery
umbre
```

[image]

Reference Website:[SQL Practice](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3d0c95ee958bee5d87a6d386042a41bf)